# how to use UFOBeacons SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

Hello friends i am using UFO Beacons for my application.

i have download SDK from http://developer.ufobeacon.com/downloads.html

but problem is that i don't understand document. and i cant access library methods.

i have tried:

```
[[UFOBeaconManager sharedInstance] StartScan:^(UFODevice *ufoDevice,
                                                   NSError *error)
     {


         if([_peripheralList containsObject:[ufoDevice valueForKey:@"state"]])
         {
             [_peripheralList replaceObjectAtIndex:
              [_peripheralList indexOfObject:[ufoDevice valueForKey:@"state"]] withObject:[ufoDevice valueForKey:@"state"]];


         }
         else
         {

             if (ufoDevice != nil)
             {
                 [_peripheralList addObject:[ufoDevice valueForKey:@"state"]];

             }

         }

     }];
```

this function returns in range beacons.
but i can't use library methods.

please help if you know about it..

Comment: What library methods are you talking about?

Comment: http://developer.ufobeacon.com/downloads.html

Comment: download SDK and open document

Comment: You say, that you can't use the library, are there any error messages, what do you get? What is not working.

Comment: out of range beacon method not calling.

Comment: and yes StartScan method not calling continues.

Comment: You need to provide more information and better explain what you tried and what exactly does not work. E.g. what is "StartScan method not calling continues", there is no "continues" in StartScan closure? Is the error var set? Is error nil? You need to provide all of this for people being able to help you. Please edit you question and do not post all in the comments. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask